# Statistical Comparison of two different waves

Tags: p-value, descriptive-statistics

I have two waves data for a couple of cities and I need a comparison
            W I     W II
City A      10,000  10,100
City B      200     202 
City C      1500    1515
There is a 10% increase of the values in all cities from WaveI to WaveII. My question is which city has "Statistically Significant" increase in comparison to other cities, which statistical measure/test can be used for this sort of comparison?

Comment: You don't need test, increments is same.

Comment: What is waves data? Could you describe it a bit more?

Comment: It is the data of brand value of 3 cities, the project is to be run on monthly basis and this is the data of first two months, waveI is for 1st month and waveII is for 2nd month..